# when i scroll page then javascript problem is Count Up

Tags: javascript

The problem is found when page scroll. If I scroll the page, automatically count up javascript error.
The error is found only when I scroll the page. Otherwise, no error found.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined :

```
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (app.js:25)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:648)
at init.each (jquery.min.js:270)
at HTMLDocument.onScroll (app.js:22)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3074)
at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.min.js:2750)
```

This is my `js` code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('actived');
        })
        $(this).addClass('actived');
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2}, 500, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#main-menu .my-link').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#main-menu .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link').removeClass("actived");
            currLink.addClass("actived");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("actived");
        }
    });
};
```

My Html Structure this, Basically, I want to, when my page scroll then shows active class in my navbar & when section change then active change.

```
<nav class="my-main-menu navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu">
         <ul class="navbar-nav nav-content">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#demo" class="nav-link my-link">Work</a>  
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#about" class="nav-link my-link">About Me</a>  
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#blog-area" class="nav-link my-link">Blog</a>  
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="contact-us.html" class="nav-link my-link">Contact</a>  
            </li>
         </ul>
         <!--navbar-nav-->
      </div>
      <!--collapse end-->
   </div>
   <!--end contaner-->
</nav>
<!--navbar end-->
<!-- hero area-->
<section id="hero">
   <div class="container">
   </div>
   <!--end container-->
</section>
<!--demo -->
<section id="demo">
   <div class="container">
   </div>
   <!-- end container -->
</section>
<!-- about -->
<section id="about">
   <div class="container">
   </div>
   <!-- end container -->
</section>
<!-- review -->
<section id="review">
   <div class="container">
   </div>
   <!-- end container -->
</section>
<!-- blog -->
<section id="blog-area">
   <div class="container">
   </div>
   <!-- container end -->
</section>
```

Comment: Just something I noticed, missing a semi-colon after closing `$('a').each` in your `document.ready`.

Comment: Hi Uttsho, Could you please share more information about your HTML structure? It seems something is undefined on page and scroll event listener is calling that again and again.

Comment: @interesting-name-here In javascript, semi-colons are optional.

Comment: @SebastianVittersø I get that but it doesn't follow the rest of the code which is why it stood out to me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the following section of JavaScript and HTML:

```js
$('#main-menu .my-link').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#main-menu .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link').removeClass("actived");
            currLink.addClass("actived");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("actived");
        }
    });
```

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="contact-us.html" class="nav-link my-link">Contact</a>  
</li>
```

The jQuery is attempting to get each main menu link element, and get another HTML element based on the `href` value. However, the `href` value of the link above does not refer to an element and therefore, an error is thrown.

To fix this, you need to change the following line:

```js
$('#main-menu .my-link').each(function () {
// to
$('#main-menu .my-link[href^="#"]').each(function () {
```

This ensures that only main menu link elements, that have a `href` value which starts with a hash, get selected.